# How do we perform an action if the roles for content are changed?

Tags: python, plone

I wish to trigger a mail, when the roles are changed for a piece of content via the Sharing tab. How can this be achieved? I am aware of triggering a mail if an object is modified, but not if permission is changed/added.

Comment: How do you change the permission on the content? Using a workflow transition (publish/submit for review/retract etc.), using the Sharing tab or using the ZMI?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I use the sharing tab

Comment: Those are roles; corrected your question.

Answer (score 1):

Customize Plone through your custom add-on http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getstarted/index.html

You probably need to patch the sharing tabs to fire a custom event which is fired when Sharing tabs is saved.

Events http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/events.html

This customization could be done via

overrides http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/zcml.html#overrides

or monkey-patching http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc/monkeypatch.html

Then create a content-rule condition for your custom event:

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-content-rule-conditions-and-actions/adding-the-condition

Answer (score 0):

The content rules framework is built on Zope events; when content is modified an event is sent out, and the content rules subscribes to that event, is notified and performs configured actions.

Unfortunately, neither the sharing tab nor the underlying Zope access control framework emit events (that part of Zope pre-dates events by quite a few years).

You'd have to:

1. Customize the Sharing tab view (`plone.app.workflow.browser.sharing`) to emit a custom event when a roles are added or removed.
2. Register this event type with the content rules engine; you need to register the event interface with a `IRuleEventType`:

   ```
    <interface
     interface="your.package.interfaces.IRolesChangedEvent"
     type="plone.contentrules.rule.interfaces.IRuleEventType"
     name="Roles added or removed on this object"
     />
   ```
3. Create a condition that can be triggered by the new event type. This procedure is [documented in this Plone.org knowledgebase article](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-content-rule-conditions-and-actions).